# Django admin: datetime is displayed in UTC despite settings

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-admin

I have this in the DB:
25.0|120|CashApp|0.0|0|1|2022-03-03 22:05:17.025000

This in the settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern' # = EST
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

And this in the admin.py:

```
def timestamp_(self, obj):
    return obj.timestamp.strftime("%d %b, %I:%M %p") # :%S
timestamp_.admin_order_field = 'timestamp'
```

And on the page it's displayed like this:   03 Mar, 10:05 PM

From what I understand it stores the timestamp in UTC in the DB, which is perfect, but why it displays it in UTC on the page? I've read that if I don't do activate(), the current timezone will be the same as default timezone, which should be EST in my case. What am I missing?

Comment: Since you're manually formatting the datetime, you'll have to do the timezone conversion yourself. You are returning a string, hence django has no way of knowing that this is a datetime object.

Comment: @xyres, ah, my bad. Indeed, I thought obj.timestamp will be converted already, but it's too early at this stage. I'll try! Was suspecting this point, that's why I've added the custom field code, and truly it's the reason:)

Comment: @xyres: Worked, thank you! Don't know if it deserves a full fledged answer (which I'll upvote), or maybe it's a duplicate?